# Align a textview to the center of progressbar in Android

Tags: android

I would align a textview to the center of progressbar in Android.

Codes :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oyunhamletv"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/hamlebar"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:maxHeight="35dp"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:scaleY="8"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:max="100"
    />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bartext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hamle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

    />

    </LinearLayout>
```

But it looks like :

[image: photo progressbar and textview]

How can I resolve this problem?

I need your help.

Comment: you mean when progess is update,textview position is also update to center as per progress ??

Comment: @Niceumang No. I would update the position of textview to the center of progressbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Relative Layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/hamlebar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:maxHeight="35dp"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:scaleY="8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bartext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Hamle" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @HasanGüleç I am Glat it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that hardcoding width and height will give the same result on different devices, better to use **match_parant** or **wrap_content**. See below code let me know.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/hamlebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:max="100" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bartext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hamle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```